# ARM Assembly Language uART0 Input Output, What am I doing wrong.

Tags: assembly, input, arm, output, uart

Write two (2) ARM assembly language subroutines, called output_char and read_char.
These subroutines will allow a user to enter a character and display the character in PuTTy via the UART.
All user input should be echoed back to the display

I tried writing the code but it did not work.

```
U0LSR EQU 0x14          
register EQU 0xE000C000


    STMFD SP!,{lr}  

read_character
    LDR r0, =0xE000C014
    LDRB r1, [r0]
    BIC r1, r1, #0xFFFFFFFE
    CMP r1, #0
    BEQ read_character
    LDR r6, =register
    LDR r2, [r6]



output_character
    LDR r0, =0xE000C014
    LDRB r1, [r0]
    BIC  r1, r1, #0xFFFFFFEF
    MOV r1, r1, LSR #1
    CMP r1, #0
    BEQ output_character
    LDR r6, =register
    STR r2, [r6]

    LDMFD sp!, {lr}
    BX lr
```

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025929/arm-uart0-input-output-lpc2138-what-am-i-doing-wrong) ?

Comment: I actually put the question. Sorry this is my first time here. I will delete the earlier question.

Comment: This could be cleaned up of course, but assuming you have initialized the uart properly this looks okay.  You dont need the lsr of 1 in the output routine, that does nothing for you.

Comment: What did not work? Also give your magic numbers some names, and tell us which uart (it may be usefull ), and a link to the data sheet.

Comment: you have wrapped these two routines with a save of lr which you dont need and if these two routines are supposed to be part of some single routine that is called over and over again you need to declare that name and make it global

Comment: try starting with a  loop that does output characters only say 0x30 to 0x39.  wrap that loop with for(r2=0x30;r2<=0x39;r2++) but in asm of course.  If that half of this code doesnt work then it doesnt matter if your rx works.  Once your tx works then focus on the rx...divide your problem in half

Comment: the bic is going to be replaced with AND by the assembler might as well just use AND...

Comment: @dwelch and output_character eats stack (you will get a stack underflow). The push link register is at the top where it can not be called as no entry point (label).

Comment: We don't know if your UART is set up correctly or if your cable etc. is wired right.  The number of ways that serial comms cannot work is ledgendary, and we can't fix code and hardware by blog.

Comment: Start with @dwelch suggestion.  Just send something, anything repeatedly, and fiddle with stuff until you get SOMETHING at the other end.  Even if you get garbage 'cos bad baud rate, clock divider etc, it's a million times better than nothing.  Move on up from there.

Comment: @richard nothing in the code uses the stack except the push and pop so there is no need to preserve the lr, if there had been a bl or blx then that is when you would need to preserve lr on the stack.

Comment: a single write to 0xE000C000 of some printable character should demonstrate if the uart is up.  that would be step one if that works then you can either wait a while and do another write, or you can start to poll the tx empty status bit.  And that leads to maybe doing a loop of some number of things, if you are properly polling the tx empty you will get all the characters if you are not you may only get the first one or get some mangled one or get a few it depends on a few things...

Comment: How would we write to 0xE000C000?

Comment: Are you sure that the *uart* is both byte (8bit) and word (32bit) addressable?  You can try `LDRB r2, [r6]`.

Comment: @dwelch sorry for the miss-understanding. I was agreeing with you, but also adding that I noticed another problem with the stack instructions. I will also add now that there is no return from subroutine instruction. (the paragraph above the code describes it as 2 subroutines).

Comment: @richard, duh right I see what you are talking about...And right there are a number of problems, it is not written as two subroutines at all.. or even one as written...

Comment: Hey guys I figured it out..I was doing something wrong in the output section..I was clearing the 5th bit (as in 4th bit starting from 0) instead of the 5th bit (which is the 6th bit actually starting from 0). That is why it wasn't running. I need help with another thing though and I posted it on another question. Please help me out if you guys can

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is related

http://csserver.evansville.edu/~blandfor/EE311/ARMLecture/UARTNotes.pdf

Considering these are supposed to be two separate functions, the previous comments above apply.  Also, I will assume since the problem does not refer to initializing the UART, that it does work successfully otherwise.  The STMFD/LDMFD/BX triplex should be associated with both functions.  Also, considering the ARM procedure call standard

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf

you probably should limit yourself to R0-R3 in your procedures, if possible.  If you need more, you need to add them to the STMFD/LDMFD instructions so you don't modify registers without returning them to their previous state.

The way the problem statement is written, the read_char function needs to call the write_char function to echo the character typed back to the screen.  That is missing in your answer.  It looks like the register holding the character is the same as the register sending the character, so that's good.  Otherwise the read_character function looks OK.

Your write_character function doesn't look quite correct however, your BIC 0xFFFF FFEF doesn't look right.  You want to be looking at the Transmitter Empty bit, you should be using 0xFFFF FFBF.  As a point of style, I would recommend using AND with the bit set you want versus BIC and the inverse.  Makes it easier to see.  If you aren't seeing anything on your output, this is most likely the problem since the BI (break indicator) bit at LSR[4] is probably never going high, so your code is looping forever.

Lastly, the problem statement says to use read_char and output_char as your function names, so you need to add those labels to the STMFD instructions for each. Your BEQ is fine, it needs to loop back to the register read from the line status register, so it needs a separate target label.